# regularity theory of parabolic equations in Heisenberg group

Tags: parabolic-pde, heisenberg-groups

I'm trying to understand if there are regularity results for mild solutions of partial differential equations in Heisenberg group. In [this](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272398/1-s2.0-S0022039621X00332/1-s2.0-S0022039621006835/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEFMaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIDj3Mt8HQ27PIfBx%2BxOA%2FTRLThx%2F6njyI6gRR27SoXCdAiEAwiwc%2FqLMIVBPJ212ZzFDCnqg2tZ8tdfDP9xkPwYlHO8qvAUI2%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDGA1EOidtQTa%2FClUXiqQBRYuJasxtXB4OHnu0LCHyfYLN7e73BkcGWv3DaFQ3NWFEa1q65s7T7lKCkhGS1%2B5QKuF0y%2FxVK8VQlwTNkcKOqTngHz0N9jQr214FaJUqzgh4V95XmTiwpqcEIs3VaDMkXzMKtvk%2B7mixUCmcJqpWyckS9eKoOOgIt84YOqm%2Bmr%2BnQsXBm7DGgfMPoIxq5L2scem80akTAXeOEquJwxHfjUEgQeVoVErWIl0p1pPExgL9sCoyjzTl6rzs4NpTWq4vOzrh73m7CKtR4Rj1xiPtTfVOAQqsAgSj24jAw%2FisjfVwRveEoiUypqls0CGT8Tq%2B5HBhqE%2BHtFlBCWNwZwMlaM8BIzH2pzU%2FSrBjbqs%2BCZ85CHS2fn2oJQY40y7sO28pIVp6viUN1Vg2Qx7EVOjqlT4AtaprkIBE1O0tDWSGCe0E8bZpySSsyMryLY82lPw2d7KG5eqtyoGkfI4RzZdUT1js4PNu8jIBx6J0GG3w1ZqYzAbjbeNLbNvbo000uVtBN5xPBdamWFkVe5GkLy3dHXa13hUBQvXadzVJCJwwjwC4bq3l5qK%2FN5OILcoEVHsD%2BnhfBQcXo0Vh8R1IXsV%2FiRMCvW9hhirEa7CpYEGzvRRsDk5EkxP4wUHiDJeW%2BIiOOsylXnuD3vj3zYzXTR%2FehZRjVZy0Doan8P8EK1rlp4%2FxyQ6sAvhc6E72HyKBYZDOhIiH2VmnWPeDpo%2B48m4r64CGSn1u3natjVI1VCz%2F5VAUw1ZIPIYzNMDDA7u3yNNQIKsZqtoPA5DsX8vEOhgCvXzPZSXJrqVWQi26zT2HFY%2FZs%2BpbDKWkJ%2BBEYWdGBid9WM6ljnlpopNrIdBTzV5svTeYZaVyc8oZkPPaW9YTxBtMMu28KUGOrEBFghBFwsIZ5Xvoft9Mm3kBG53qyRQSXVRCc2UP5MiTuLxYX3kZnk%2F99TL5c6HMAsNETUB7vIsZ7MUHW1LZSoPIL1OGgXyRj5rirROWudjEh7s%2FX6jHfvjfvVQztYf%2BoEK%2FghtyGxtcVv%2BDKT3hy2ojSBRfKHAjkazfrx1FpDBCaZ49edTx4TM8%2FqAqXkoOqSJEUb7k52coy%2Ff7sbUmdeD5adYKCga5y%2B2tf3efsbidGSo&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230722T190923Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4BFQTVKE%2F20230722%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1f0f386f1ad4c085607283204b3ac6d285a1422ee4d69ef47bf0f5db9deab89a&hash=b3fbf34b652fcaa5cc65dfd3e92bf1ac5b679a31c67f9b916954ea74eb6dcc27&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022039621006835&tid=spdf-487882ee-cc55-43dc-b156-d2ccc848836f&sid=ab0d1b672dbf554c394bfd78d33c2293d118gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=041459030f07020e5702&rr=7eadfa4a4c932555&cc=br) paper (Theorem 1.3 (iii) and proof of Theorem 1.1) the author states that there is a classical solution of

$$
\begin{cases}
u_t -  L u =  f(u)& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{H}^n \times (0,T), \\   
u(0) =  {u}_{0}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{H}^n 
\end{cases}.
$$

(on unimodular Lie groups, in particular Heisenberg group),
but I don't understand why, given that he obtained the solution through the integral operator,
\begin{equation}
Fu(t)= e^{ t\Delta_{\mathbb{H}} }u_0 + \int_{0}^{t} e^{(t-s)\Delta_{\mathbb{H}}} f(u(s)) ds.
\end{equation}

when researching a lot, I found a result of regularity [see theorem 7.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.10605.pdf), now I would like to know if this is applicable for this PDE, since there is a restriction $u \in L^p((0,T), W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega) )$, with $2<p \leq 4$ and the proof of theorem 1.1 of [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272398/1-s2.0-S0022039621X00332/1-s2.0-S0022039621006835/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEFMaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIDj3Mt8HQ27PIfBx%2BxOA%2FTRLThx%2F6njyI6gRR27SoXCdAiEAwiwc%2FqLMIVBPJ212ZzFDCnqg2tZ8tdfDP9xkPwYlHO8qvAUI2%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDGA1EOidtQTa%2FClUXiqQBRYuJasxtXB4OHnu0LCHyfYLN7e73BkcGWv3DaFQ3NWFEa1q65s7T7lKCkhGS1%2B5QKuF0y%2FxVK8VQlwTNkcKOqTngHz0N9jQr214FaJUqzgh4V95XmTiwpqcEIs3VaDMkXzMKtvk%2B7mixUCmcJqpWyckS9eKoOOgIt84YOqm%2Bmr%2BnQsXBm7DGgfMPoIxq5L2scem80akTAXeOEquJwxHfjUEgQeVoVErWIl0p1pPExgL9sCoyjzTl6rzs4NpTWq4vOzrh73m7CKtR4Rj1xiPtTfVOAQqsAgSj24jAw%2FisjfVwRveEoiUypqls0CGT8Tq%2B5HBhqE%2BHtFlBCWNwZwMlaM8BIzH2pzU%2FSrBjbqs%2BCZ85CHS2fn2oJQY40y7sO28pIVp6viUN1Vg2Qx7EVOjqlT4AtaprkIBE1O0tDWSGCe0E8bZpySSsyMryLY82lPw2d7KG5eqtyoGkfI4RzZdUT1js4PNu8jIBx6J0GG3w1ZqYzAbjbeNLbNvbo000uVtBN5xPBdamWFkVe5GkLy3dHXa13hUBQvXadzVJCJwwjwC4bq3l5qK%2FN5OILcoEVHsD%2BnhfBQcXo0Vh8R1IXsV%2FiRMCvW9hhirEa7CpYEGzvRRsDk5EkxP4wUHiDJeW%2BIiOOsylXnuD3vj3zYzXTR%2FehZRjVZy0Doan8P8EK1rlp4%2FxyQ6sAvhc6E72HyKBYZDOhIiH2VmnWPeDpo%2B48m4r64CGSn1u3natjVI1VCz%2F5VAUw1ZIPIYzNMDDA7u3yNNQIKsZqtoPA5DsX8vEOhgCvXzPZSXJrqVWQi26zT2HFY%2FZs%2BpbDKWkJ%2BBEYWdGBid9WM6ljnlpopNrIdBTzV5svTeYZaVyc8oZkPPaW9YTxBtMMu28KUGOrEBFghBFwsIZ5Xvoft9Mm3kBG53qyRQSXVRCc2UP5MiTuLxYX3kZnk%2F99TL5c6HMAsNETUB7vIsZ7MUHW1LZSoPIL1OGgXyRj5rirROWudjEh7s%2FX6jHfvjfvVQztYf%2BoEK%2FghtyGxtcVv%2BDKT3hy2ojSBRfKHAjkazfrx1FpDBCaZ49edTx4TM8%2FqAqXkoOqSJEUb7k52coy%2Ff7sbUmdeD5adYKCga5y%2B2tf3efsbidGSo&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230722T190923Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4BFQTVKE%2F20230722%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1f0f386f1ad4c085607283204b3ac6d285a1422ee4d69ef47bf0f5db9deab89a&hash=b3fbf34b652fcaa5cc65dfd3e92bf1ac5b679a31c67f9b916954ea74eb6dcc27&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022039621006835&tid=spdf-487882ee-cc55-43dc-b156-d2ccc848836f&sid=ab0d1b672dbf554c394bfd78d33c2293d118gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=041459030f07020e5702&rr=7eadfa4a4c932555&cc=br)  of establishes that $u \in C([0,\infty), L^q(\mathbb{H}^n) )$. Thanks advance!